# Active sync issues with 8.3 - Calendar items missing

Tags: calendar, ios, exchange-activesync

I'm responsible for many iOS devices that sync to Exchange using Activesync.  I see a problem with iOS 8.3 where appointments randomly are missing from the local device.

Is anyone aware of this issue or know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can usually resolve this sort of issue by contacting Apple support and getting a debug profile/build to load onto one device and track down the iOS errors and correlate them with the exchange server logs.

Alternate methods would include using Xcode to look at the logs on the iOS device if you are lucky enough to have relevant logs in the main log. My guess is you'll need specific logging on both sides to troubleshoot and then address this.

While you're on with Apple support, ask if they have a current exchange configuration guide - often you can get suggested settings rather than having to systematically change things server side which is never fun even if you have a development server to test with. Testing in production is not something I like to even consider when you can get at the logs and know what's happening with a known amount of work.

Comment: Is suppor the only way to get the debug build? I'm a developer and don't see a debug build here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/

Comment: @LamonteCristo I always go through support initially since Apple can then log another customer needing assistance troubleshooting this. Once a critical mass of questions come in, things like self-service and KB articles on how to fix this are then produced.

Comment: Got it.  Pardon my ignorance, is apple support only available to people with an active Apple Care contract? I'm an android user with a Macbook, who is the Exchange admin. Never used an iPhone

Comment: @LamonteCristo When you contact Apple support they will let you know if you need to pay for an incident.  If you have many devices, contact your Apple sales rep and they will make sure you get the support you need - they are especially accommodating of IT staff that are eager to support Apple customers. Some support is complementary for everyone, some support is paid for as part of the hardware purchase our stuff for purchase or a paid AppleCare plan. Worst case is you have to pay for one incident.